# constantly crash on video card

Tags: windows-7, video, graphics-card

I have this problem with my graphic-card(video card). Video card constantly crash because driver stopped. This is the massage that i get:

```
Display driver stopped responding and has recovered.
Display driver NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver , Version 285.62 stopped
responding and has successfully recovered.
```

Video card : MSI GTX470 Twin Frozr

Motherboard:Asus P8Z68 V-Pro

Tried reinstalling drivers but doesn't help.

Any ideas what can be ?

Comment: have you tried these steps: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2665946?

Comment: Yes, and nothing help from there

Comment: Please explain why is downvote for ?

Comment: Your question is vague and we need more details before we can answer your question.

Comment: This driver is not the latest, please update it and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Update your drivers, for sure. This also seems odd, but try leaving the PC off for a night afterwards. With my SLI setup, occasionally the drivers will start crashing, and I will see artifacting occur. If I update my drivers (even to the same version) and leave the computer to sit off for a night, it's entirely fine the next day. I still have yet to find any reason as to why.

Comment: Drivers are the latest on official web site.

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: windows 7 ultimate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to a spare graphics card? How long have you had that graphics card? What is the cooling like in your computer?

I had a very similar issue, which after time funny lines started to appear on my screen and in the end I had to get a new graphics card. I've since got it working again using this technique: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aK7RZjAC-qE. I only did this after the new graphics card, as purely a test to see if it works.

Comment: The computer work 4-5 hours per day and i had this video card from 6-7 months. I downloaded the latest driver from official web site but still same popup appear..

Comment: So it doesn't sound like it has been over used. Mine was on for up to 12 hours on some days for 2 years. I tried the latest drivers when mine had the same issue, and they didn't work. Does the motherboard have any video outputs, or do you have a spare card to try?

Comment: with onboard video i don't have this problem. I'll try other video on my motherboard and will give my video to someone to try. I start thinking probable video card is broken.